# MOgre multiple window bug

Tags: ogre, multi-window

Good day, everybody! I have got some troubles in creating two or more mogre window in one application. I'm using library from Leslie Godwin's project: [www.codeproject.com/Articles/29190/Blend-the-OGRE-Graphics-Engine-into-your-WPF-proje](http://codeproject.com/Articles/29190/Blend-the-OGRE-Graphics-Engine-into-your-WPF-proje)

But when I try to create new window with help of the initialization function like this:
 `new Window1().Show();` my program crashes with AccessViolationException on `RenderOneFrame` function.
 Am I going on a wrong way to create new window? If it is so,please, could you share a snippet of a code, that implements multi window approach. 
If this method is quite good, what is the reason of this bug?

P.S. this is the only trouble that can't let us to develop the application. So it is very important to know, what the solution is.

Thank in advance!